# Resultset getDate() returned incorrect date value

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, date, jdbc, resultset

This error happen in my application when I try run the following:

```
SELECT send_day FROM types WHERE ID_TYPE = 4
```

The query execution returned that date with 2 days before of column value.

The recovering of this value in Java app is this:

```
java.sql.Date dataSQL = retorno.getDate(1);
```

I'm using SQLJDB4.0 driver and database version is 2008.

Some answers for post comments:
The value of database is *2013-08-22* and the return is *2013-08-20*
My timezone is **UTC-03:00** . In the database, I exec the following command: 
 `select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` which return: *2013-08-22 11:49:12.4010367* **-03:00**

Comment: Perhaps, like Excel, Java uses 1899-12-30 as "day 0" instead of 1900-01-01?

Comment: Please include the value as it is in your database, and the value as retrieved from the `ResultSet` and your local timezone and the (actual or expected) timezone of the data stored in the database.

Comment: Java uses 1970-01-01 as "day 0". Probably problem with time zone (see getDate(int columnIndex) vs. getDate(int columnIndex, Calendar cal))

Comment: The value of database is 2013-08-22 and the return is 2013-08-20

Comment: My timezone is UTC-03:00.
In the database, I exec the following command: 
select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() which return:
2013-08-22 11:49:12.4010367 -03:00

Comment: Timezone diferences with 2 days? It's possible?

Comment: @Rodolfo Please edit that into your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok, the post has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the SQLJDBC for 4-4.0 version and the problem has been resolved.